# Selecting item from JS drop menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, watir

new to Watir and trying to select items in an unordered JS list.  I'm using watir-classic and testing in IE with Ruby v1.9.3p392.

```
<div id="ctl00_content" style="text-align: left; background: #fff;">
 <script type="text/javascript"> … </script>
 <div id="ctl00_breadCrumb" class="navBar"> … </div>
 <div id="ctl00_menuBarUpdatePanel">
  <div id="ctl00_menuBar" class="menuBar">
   <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <div class="menu">
        <ul>
         <div id="ctl00_MenuBarButtons" class="menuBarButtons">
          <li id="ctl00_AddMenu" style="display:inline;"> … </li>
          <li id="ctl00_ChangeCustodyMenu" style="display:inline;">
             Change Custody
           <ul>
            <li id="ctl00_CheckInMenuItem" style="display:inline;">
            <li id="ctl00_CheckOutMenuItem" style="display:inline;">
            <li id="ctl00_ReceiveMenuItem" style="display:inline;">
            <li id="ctl00_ReturnMenuItem" style="display:inline;">  
            <li id="ctl00_DropOffMenuItem" style="display:inline;">
              <a onclick="window.location = '/WebSite/PropertyItems.aspx?action=dropOff'; return false;" href="">
                Drop-off
```

I'm trying to select Drop-off (the last item in the list) and have attempted using the following:

```
browser.ul(:id,"ctl00_ChangeCustodyMenu").li(:text,"Drop-off").click 
browser.div(:id, "ctl00_MenuBarButtons").li(:index, 1).link(:index, 4).click
```

... but then read that I can't select items in Watir unless I can see it. I started to test with fire_event("onclick") with the following tip: "I firstly need to fire_event("onmouseover") which selects the item then fire_event("onclick")."

So I try this:

```
browser.li(:id,"ctl00_ChangeCustodyMenu").fire_event("onclick")
```

This method will flash the 'Change Custody' menu, but not drop down the list with the 'Drop-down' item. Hence, I am not able to select the item on the list. The Change Custody list will drop once the user hovers over the menu in normal operation.

How do I select the JS drop-down list and select an item in an unordered list? Do I need to use webdriver's select_list, or am I just missing something? Watir-classic seems pretty straight forward and should handle this, but maybe the JS structure is tricky here.

Thanks for the help!

Shannon

[image: Menu]

Comment: Do you know what event the dropdown is looking for? If you are using watir-webdriver, you can try using the `hover` method.

Comment: It sounds like I just need to add watir-webdriver and change the scripts so I can use methods like `hover` and `when_present_click`, as watir-classic is not robust enough with some JS functions. I'll make the switch and follow-up. Thanks.

Comment: It should be possible to get it to work with watir-classic. The problem is always just figuring out what your application is looking for. If you create a runnable example (eg on jsFiddle), it would make it a lot easier to help.

Comment: So I'm not sure of this theory, but I was not able to drop this list in using watir-classic with Ruby v1.9.3p392. Justin recommended watir-webdriver, but I was still having issues. So I upgraded to Ruby v2.0.0p247 with watir-webdriver and am now able to use    `hover` and    `fire_event('onClick')`. Maybe there was an issue in Ruby v1.9.3p392 or something, but using Ruby v2 w/webdriver seems to work! Thanks again.